# Stretch div to the top of other variable height div without using absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I have two divs stacked vertically. I'm attempting to stretch the lower div to the top of the upper div when a button is clicked. This works well when the bottom div uses absolute positioning, updating the `top` property of the lower div as needed.

The issue comes when the top div is a variable height. I'd like the lower div to sit at the bottom of the top div when not stretched. How can the below code be updated so that the bottom div will always sit below the top div, even if it's height changes?

[Example using absolute positioning](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZJVag)

Comment: If you don't mind the lower div's bottom stretching to the bottom of the wrapper (maybe adjusting wrapper's height?) you can apply `position: absolute;` with `expanded` class. This way it's top part works as expected while still being responsive to upper div height. [Here's the example](https://codepen.io/sc0rpide/pen/rbzPbY)

Answer (score 1):

For this case you should avoid using `position: absolute` as make elements stop affect one to each other. Instead I recommend you to use *flexbox* combined width min-width and max-width for both elements.
If your component is always going to have a fix height (300px in your example), then can happen that content overflows the container.
I little more of design context would have help, so hope this solutions works for you.

```js
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle('expanded');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10rem;
}

div {
  width: 12rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.stationary {
  min-height: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: min-height 1s, max-height 1s;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
.expanded .stationary {
  max-height: 0;
  min-height: 0%;
}

.expanding {
  flex: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  background: blue;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.expanded .expanding {
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stationary">
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
  </div>
  <div class="expanding">
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
    Random text that makes this a variable height div....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the option is not to expand `blue` div, but to collapse red `div`.
Here is one way how to do it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrzBja

Trick is to make wrapper's background blue.

The only problem is that `max-height` needs to be set to some arbitrary value (in my example `100%`) so transition looks a little bit delayed.

I hope You get some inspiration from it to improve Your solution further.